# Resizing an image in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, ihttphandler

I have the following code in my IHttpHandler:

```
            Dim MemoryStream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream

            MemoryStream1.Write(SqlDataReader1("cover"), 0, SqlDataReader1("cover").Length - 1)

            Dim Bitmap1 As System.Drawing.Bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(MemoryStream1)

            Dim Width1 As Integer = Bitmap1.Width
            Dim Height1 As Integer = Bitmap1.Height

            Dim Width2 As Integer = 90
            Dim Height2 As Integer = Height1 * Width1 / Width1

            Dim Bitmap2 As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width2, Height2)

            Dim Graphics1 As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap2)

            Graphics1.DrawImage(Bitmap1, 0, 0, Width2, Height2)

            Dim MemoryStream2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream

            Bitmap2.Save(MemoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

            context.Response.BinaryWrite(MemoryStream2.ToArray)
```

It works but I'm not sure that it is the right way to resize an image. How to simplify that code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's the list of problems with it: http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/  I'd suggest using [my library](http://imageresizing.net), this is not something you can cram into 1 or even 10 pages of code without having serious flaws in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the code is correct, but there are some problems with it:

- You are skipping the last byte when you write into the first memory stream. The last property in the `Write` call should be the length, not the length minus one.
- Your calculation of `Height2` is incorrect. The expression `Height1 * Width1 / Width1` will always evaluate to the value of `Height1`. You should use `Height1 * Width2 / Width1` instead.
- You are not disposing your memory streams, bitmaps or graphics objects. Use `Using` blocks to make sure that the objects are disposed.

You can simplify the code somewhat by creating the first memory stream from the byte array instead of writing the array to the stream:

```
Using MemoryStream1 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(SqlDataReader1("cover"))

  Using Bitmap1 As System.Drawing.Bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(MemoryStream1)

    Dim Width1 As Integer = Bitmap1.Width
    Dim Height1 As Integer = Bitmap1.Height

    Dim Width2 As Integer = 90
    Dim Height2 As Integer = Height1 * Width2 / Width1

    Using Bitmap2 As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width2, Height2)

      Using Graphics1 As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap2)

        Graphics1.DrawImage(Bitmap1, 0, 0, Width2, Height2)

      End Using

      Using MemoryStream2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        Bitmap2.Save(MemoryStream2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(MemoryStream2.ToArray)

      End Using

    End Using

  End Using

End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Function ResizeImage(imgToResize As Image, size As Size) As Byte()
        Dim sourceWidth As Integer = imgToResize.Width
        Dim sourceHeight As Integer = imgToResize.Height

        Dim nPercent As Single = 0
        Dim nPercentW As Single = 0
        Dim nPercentH As Single = 0

        nPercentW = (CSng(size.Width) / CSng(sourceWidth))
        nPercentH = (CSng(size.Height) / CSng(sourceHeight))

        If nPercentH < nPercentW Then
            nPercent = nPercentH
        Else
            nPercent = nPercentW
        End If

        Dim destWidth As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(sourceWidth * nPercent))
        Dim destHeight As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(sourceHeight * nPercent))

        Dim b As New Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(DirectCast(b, Image))
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight)
        g.Dispose()

        Return b.ToByteArray()
    End Function
```

This function will resize an image to a specified size keeping its proporstion. It was in C# and I put it through an online converter so may not be 100% correct

ToByteArray() is an extension method I wrote to store the image in a DB i can give you that also if you like.

Comment: this will **shrink** the image so the whole image will **fit** inside the `size` dimensions(so blank space may appear left-right or top-bottom if displayed on a `size` dimension container that has different aspect ratio thanthe original image).To **enlarge** the image to **fill** all the `size` dimensions just change the `<` to `>` in the `If nPercentH < nPercentW Then` line. (but this will actuallyreturn a bigger than `size` dimensions image-then its up to you what part of imageyou will useand how -for example from left-top or the centered part,to display in a containerwith `size` dimensions)